# how to pass dropdown selected value from Dropdownlist to a textbox using mvc5 with same view?

Tags: jquery, razor, text, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

I am new to mvc.As a beginner i am trying to pass a dropdown value from a DropdownList to a textbox within same view with a button click.
I do some code. but dosen't work. I can populate data on drop sown list but actually submit change event dosen't work.
how can I overcome the problem. 
Here is my image
[Dropdownlist to textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl9e1.png)

My  Dropdown.cshtml View code is here-

```
@model LoginForm.Models.UserModel

@{
                ViewBag.Title = "Dropdown";
}

<h2>Dropdown List</h2>

<div class="form-horizontal">

</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Dropdown", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:50px">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @(Html.DropDownList("DropdowenList", new SelectList(ViewBag.AllNameList, "CustomerId",
                                                                                "UserName", 0), "Select ...", new { @class = "form-control" }))

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            <br />
            <br />
            @Html.TextBox("txtName")

        </div>
    </div>

}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#DropdowenList').change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $('#txtName').val(selectedValue);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My HomeCoontroller.Cs  code is here-

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Dropdown(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.Flag = true;
        DropdowncCass dp = new DropdowncCass();
        var allName = dp.GetUserInfo();
        ViewBag.AllNameList = allName;
        Session["allName"] = allName;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: The JS code seem fine, what actually doesn't work during `change` event? Are you checked the console already?

Comment: yes, it's actually dosen't work on change event. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Are you want to handle `change` event from dropdownlist, or passing the value by button `click` event instead? If the second one is your choice, try `$('.btn').click(function () { e.preventDefault(); var selectedValue = $('#DropdowenList').val(); $('#txtName').val(selectedValue); });`. Check if you got any errors in console too.

Comment: yes.you are right. i want to pass the value by button click. i use your code but dosen't work.I think the problem is in submit button. am i missing something on submit button click event? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Oh, I think you need to use `$('.btn').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); // other stuff });` to prevent default submit button behavior. I just forgot to include event handler parameter.

Comment: I use this -
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedValue = $('#dropdownlist').val(); $('#txtName').val(selectedValue);
    });
</script>

but not work.

Comment: I created a fiddle with working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3G7Uh. Can you provide what thing doesn't work? Also you should not use `$('#dropdownlist').val();` but `$('#DropdowenList').val();` instead.

Comment: it's worked. i follow your example code. i realized i missed javascript validation and all kind of  scripting. now it's worked. but i get id as return type value. if i want to return type value as string what can i do? like selecting"Sample A"  and in textbox showing "Sample A' instead of 1. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Just use `$("#DropdowenList option:selected").text();` instead of `$('#DropdowenList').val();` and you will get the dropdown selected text.

Comment: ok. problem solved :)  thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto . thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: ok. problem solved :)  thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto . thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle submit button's `click` event to achieve your goal and use `option:selected` selector with `text()` function to set textbox value from dropdown's selected item text:

```
$(function () {
     $('.btn').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var selectedValue = $("#DropdowenList option:selected").text();
         $('#txtName').val(selectedValue);
     });
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` is necessary here because you're using `BeginForm` helper which renders `<form>` tag and the function useful to prevent default button submit behavior that posts back the form to controller action.

[This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3G7Uh) contains working example that illustrates the desired behavior.